# Sonar Cloud Gitlab Analyzes

Tags: gitlab, sonarcloud

I use Sonar Cloud to analyze my code with Gitlab CI. How it is usually in the SONAR_HOST_URL I put https://sonarcloud.io , but after the pipeline finish sonar put my analysis into INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard.Why I don't write anywhere this URL. I want the analysis to be in the cloud version.

```
sonarcloud-check:
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - choco install sonarqube-scanner.portable
    - SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"somefile" /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io" /d:sonar.login="kjhnhgffddsdt"   
    - nuget restore -ConfigFile .\nuget.config
    - MsBuild.exe ./Project/t:Rebuild
    - SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="kjhnhgffddsdt"
  only:           
    - merge_requests
    - master
    - develop
    - GitLabQualityTool
```

This is the error: INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id.
In my gitlab variables  SONAR_HOST_URL=https://sonarcloud.io

This is another version that I try:

```
analyze: 
stage: analyze
image:
  name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
  entrypoint: [""]
cache:
  key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
  paths:
    - .sonar/cache
script:
  - sonar-scanner
only:
  - master
  - IDEA-022
```

Comment: it is really hard to support you, because of missing information - how do you analyse your code? a build tool, the default scanners? which versions, how do you set the SONAR_HOST_URL? can you share your CI yml, at least in a short version, with the step. this allows us to actually grasp the problem, currently their could be a lot of reasons, why this is not working

Comment: This the part of yml:

Comment: edit your question, and add all the information to the qeustion please

Comment: did you try setting the CI Variables like SONAR_HOST_URL and SONAR_TOKEN as described in the documentation, because sonar scanner is also checking those

Comment: Yes of course SONAR_HOST_URL=https://sonarcloud.io